# How to measure the length of mitochondria from z stack fluorescent microscopy image?

Tags: microbiology, mitochondria, yeast, fluorescent-microscopy, image-processing

I have been working on yeast cells to analyse the effect of DNA damaging agents on mitochondrial structure. I have imaged my culture treated with MMS for a period of 6 hours and while observing the images, I suspect there is fragmentation of mitochondria in later point of time. So, I am wondering if I can get measurements of mitochondria using z stack images.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Can you expand on your protocol (both to encourage answers and to make it easier for other non-experts to understand both the question and the answer)? We have been doing some z-stack imaging for a separate project (imaging viral dissemination in insect tissues) but there isn't enough in your question yet for me to tell exactly where you're having problems.

Comment: Sorry for providing insufficient information. I have stained yeast cells with mito tracker dye (for mitochondrial staining) and analysed samples for 6 hours, by taking out 1 ml of culture at every one hour. While imaging culture, I captured z stack images for these 7 time points (starting from zero hour). Now, I have been looking for applications that can provide me the measurements (dimensions) of stained mitochondria using Z stacked images.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) is usually the standard software to measure cell characteristics, a little bit of a learning curve but there is a large suite of analysis methods and image adjustments/filters.